# Django - How to render a ModelForm with a Select field, specifying a disabled option?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
# Get or create a 'Not selected' category
def get_placeholder_categoy():
    category, _ = ListingCategories.objects.get_or_create(category='Not selected')
    return category


# Get default's category ID
def get_placeholder_category_id():
    return get_placeholder_categoy().id


class ListingCategories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.category}'


class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='listings')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5120, blank=True)
    img_url = models.URLField(default='https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/no-image-available-picture-coming-soon-missing-photo-image-vector-id1379257950?b=1&k=20&m=1379257950&s=170667a&w=0&h=RyBlzT5Jt2U87CNkopCku3Use3c_3bsKS3yj6InGx1I=')
    category = models.ForeignKey(ListingCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=get_placeholder_category_id, related_name='listings')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    base_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[
        MinValueValidator(0.01),
        MaxValueValidator(99999999.99)
    ])
```

With these, I have the following form:

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        exclude = ['seller', 'creation_date']
        widgets = {
            'title': TextInput(attrs=base_html_classes),
            'description': Textarea(attrs=base_html_classes),
            'img_url': URLInput(attrs=base_html_classes),
            'category': Select(attrs=base_html_classes),
            'base_price': NumberInput(attrs=base_html_classes)
        }
```

One of the available categories I have is "Not selected", since I want to allow that if at some point a category were to be removed, items can be reassigned to that one, however, when rendering the form, I will do some validation on the view function to prevent it from being submitted if the "not selected" category is sent with the form.

Because of this, I want the HTML form on the template to assign the 'disabled' attribute to the option corresponding to that category, however, I have been searching for a couple of days now without finding anything that I was able to understand to the point where I could try it.

Ideally, another thing I'd like to achieve is to be able to modify the order of the rendered options on the form so that I can move to the top 'not selected' regardless of its primary key within the model.

I am aware I can just create a form instead of a model form, or just modify the template so I manually specify how to render the form itself, but I do feel like there is a simple fix to this either on the model or on the model form that I am just not finding yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use (in model definition)

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    ..
    category = model.ForeignKey(ListingCategories, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='listings')
    ..
```

and optionally in form definition

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(ListingCategories, empty_label='Not Selected')
    ..
```

While rendering model form, a `required` attribute will be automatically added, and in form validating, it is also required. It is only in database validation that the field can be left `NULL`